# Google Analytics - have active user but missing info

Tags: google-analytics

Environment: injected Google Analytics tracking in my SharePoint Online site - all good.

Now I have been clicking pages for more than an hour and wanted to check results. I see that tracking is working (see screenshot) - at that moment there was one active user (me) and have >30 page views in a 30min time window.

[image]

Problem: reports (user and page view count) seem to be empty, but I assume that there should be at least one user and multiple page view information. Is that correct or I am misusing Google Analytics?

**Update:**
Pressed "Refresh Report" and Google fetched new data. Unfortunately, nothing changed and data still is empty.

> This report was generated on 12/04/2019 at 16:17:25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time of when the report was generated is not reflective of how "fresh" the data is. For the free version of GA, there is no SLA and it can take upwards of 2 days, but generally under 24 hours. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7084038?hl=en

Seeing the user in realtime doesn't mean the data for the reports are updated. You need to be patient and wait.

Comment: I checked results after two days and yes - results came up and now I see all I was looking for. Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

If you're seeing data in the real time reports then the standard reports should populate. This can take time though in my experience the latency is usually less than 1 hour. Are you looking at the standard reports in an entirely unfiltered view - might be worth checking to see if any filters are impacting your data though they should effect the real time reports as well.